# python syntax error on line 64 (really new to this)

Tags: python, syntax

So I'm really new to python and coding in general but I'm trying to make a program that calculates the processing power and power usage of a computer based on each part and its specifications. However, i keep getting this message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 64
    drive()
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just don't get it. What is wrong with my code? I know it's trash but I'm new and still learning. It's probably a super simple thing.

Any way here's the code:

```
  def start():
    print("* Welcome to Spicy's Processing Power / TDP Calculator! (SPPTDPC) *")
    print("* Version 0.0.5 *")
    print("** This program is still in alpha stage and isn't perfect **")
    print("If you are unsure about one of the questions, look up the specs of the part on a website like PCPartPicker or TechPowerUP")
    cpu()
def cpu():
    global r
    global cpus
    global cputdp
    name = input("What is the name of your processor?")
    c = float(input("How many cores does the "+name+" have?"))
    t = float(input("How many threads does the "+name+" have?"))
    l1 = float(input("How much L1 cache (in total) does the "+name+" have in KB?"))
    l2 = float(input("How much L2 cache (in total) does the "+name+" have in MB?"))
    l3 = float(input("How much L3 cache (in total) does the "+name+" have in MB?"))
    g = float(input("What is the clock speed (in GHz) of the "+name+"?"))
    n = float(input("What is the fabrication process of the "+name+" in nm?"))
    r = float(input("What type of RAM does the "+name+" use? Enter 3 for DDR3, 4 for DDR4, etc."))
    cputdp = float(input("What is the TDP of the "+name+"?"))
    cpus = (c+t+g+r+l2+(l1/100)+(.3*l3))/n #CPU Processing Power Formula
    print("** The "+name+" has a score of "+str(cpus)+". **")
    ram()
def ram():
  global rtdp
  global rams
  g = float(input("How much RAM does your system have (in GB?)"))
  m = float(input("What is the speed of your slowest installed DIMM? (in MHz)"))
  rtdp = float(input("How many DIMMs do you have installed?"))
  rtdp = rtdp*4
  rams = ((r+(m/500))*g)/150 #RAM Processing Power Formula
  print("** Your RAM score is "+str(rams)+". **")
  gpu()
def gpu():
  gputest()
  print("** The "+gpuname+" has a score of "+str(gpus)+". **")
  gputdp = float(input("What is the TDP of the "+gpuname+"?"))
def gputest():
    global gpuname
    global memtyp
    global gputdp
    gpuname = input("What is the name of your GPU?")
    memtyp = int(input("What type of memory does your GPU use? 0 for GDDR, 1 for HBM"))
    gputdp = float(input("What is the TDP of your GPU?"))
    if memtyp == 0:
        gddr()
    if memtyp == 1:
        hbm()
    else:
      print("Error: Please enter either 0 or 1.")
      gputest()
def gddr():
  global gpus
  gc = float(input("How many cores does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  gt = float(input("How many TMUs does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  go = float(input("How many ROPs does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  gm = float(input("How much memory (in MB) does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  gr = float(input("What type of memory does the "+gpuname+" have? Enter 3 for GDDR3, 5 for GDDR5, and 8 for GDDR5X (to account for its additional data rate)"))
  gb = float(input("What is the bus width of the "+gpuname+"?"))        
  gg = float(input("What is the clock speed of the "+gpuname+" in GHz?"))
  gmg = float(input("What is the effective memory speed of the "+gpuname+" in MHz?"))
  gn = float(input("What is the fabrication process of the "+gpuname+" in nm?"))
  gpus = (((gc/400)+(gt/25)+(go/10)+(gm/1000)+(gb/30)+(gg*2)+(gmg/1000))*((gr/gn)/25) #GDDR GPU Processing Power Formula
  drive()
def hbm():
  global gpus
  hgc = float(input("How many cores does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  hgt = float(input("How many TMUs does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  hgo = float(input("How many ROPs does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  hgm = float(input("How much memory (in MB) does the "+gpuname+" have?"))
  hgr = float(input("What type of HBM does the "+gpuname+" have? Enter 1 for HBM, 2 for HBM2, etc."))
  hgb = float(input("What is the bus width of the "+gpuname+"?"))       
  hgg = float(input("What is the clock speed of the "+gpuname+" in GHz?"))
  hgmg = float(input("What is the effective memory speed of the "+gpuname+" in MHz?"))
  hgn = float(input("What is the fabrication process of the "+gpuname+" in nm?"))
  gpus = (((hgc/400)+(hgt/25)+(hgo/10)+(hgm/1000)+(hgb/250)+(hgg*2)+(hgmg/150))/((hgr/hgn)/25) #HBM GPU Processing Power Formula
  drive()
def drive():
  print("** The "+gpuname+" has a score of "+str(gpus)+". **")
  global typ
  typ = float(input("Is your boot drive an HDD or SSD? Enter 1 for HDD, 2 for SSD."))
  if typ == 1:
    hdd()
  if typ == 2:
    ssd()
def hdd():
  global free
  global total
  global hds
  rpm = float(input("What is the RPM of your HDD?"))
  free = float(input("How much storage is available (not filled) on your boot drive (in GB)"))
  total = float(input("What is the total amount of storage on your boot drive (in GB)"))
  freespace()
  hds = (((1/p)*100)*(rpm/1000))/12 #HDD Processing Power Formula
  drivetdp()
def ssd():
  global free
  global total
  global hds
  free = float(input("How much storage is available (not filled) on your boot drive (in GB)"))
  total = float(input("What is the total amount of storage on your boot drive (in GB)"))
  freespace()
  hds = ((((1/p)*100)*5)*typ)/12 #SSD Processing Power Formula
  drivetdp()
def freespace():
  global p
  p = (free/total)*100
  print("* Your boot drive is "+str(p)+"% free. *")
def drivetdp():
  global ssdtdp
  global hddtdp
  ssdtdp = float(input("How many SSDs do you have installed in your system?"))
  ssdtdp = ssdtdp*3.25
  hddtdp = float(input("How many HDDs do you have installed in your system?"))
  hddtdp = hddtdp*8
  print("** Your boot drive's score is "+str(hds)+". **")
  final()
def final():
  global fns
  global tdp
  global psu
  print("Calculating final score...")
  fns = (cpus+gpus+hds+rams) #Final Score Formula
  print(str(fns))
  dvdtdp = float(input("How many optical drives do you have installed?"))
  dvdtdp = dvdtdp*20 #1 ODD draws around 20 watts
  fantdp = float(input("How many case fans do you have installed? (counting CPU cooler)"))
  fantdp = fantdp*5 #1 120mm fan draws around 5 watts
  usbtdp = float(input("How many USB ports does your computer have? (in total)"))
  usbtdp = usbtdp*2.5 #USB can only pull 2.5 watts
  tdp = (((cputdp+gputdp)*(4/5))+rtdp+hddtdp+ssdtdp+dvdtdp+fantdp+usbtdp)+50 #estimated max load TDP equation, the +50 watts is for the motherboard
  psu = cputdp+gputdp+rtdp+hddtdp+ssdtdp+dvdtdp+usbtdp+50 #max spec TDP equation
  print("** Your final score is... **")
  print(str(fns))
  print("** Your predicted maximum load wattage is... **")
  print(str(tdp))
  print("** I would recommend using a power supply of at least "+str(psu)+" watts. **")
  print("Thank you for using SPPC!")
  print("Copyright NFR 2018")
start()
again = input("Do you want to use the calculator again? Y/N")
if again == "Y":
    start()
#Copyright NFR 2018
```

Comment: check you brackets on the line before.

Comment: It's ALWAYS a missing parenthesis on the line before.

Comment: @Julien thanks, was 2 extra brackets i did't need. appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the future only paste the relevant lines of code and not the entire file. The error is at line 64, so a good idea would be to paste the 4-5 lines above 65 and then indicate line 64.

Now to answer the question. On line 63 you have an extra opening parentheses that never gets closed. If you look after the equals sign you open three parentheses. If you then follow all the openings and closings, there is one From the start still open.

Comment: Sorry, as i said before i literally started coding a month ago and I have never used this website before. Already figured it out. Thanks tho.

Comment: Really no worries. I just know from experience it is easier and more likely for others to help you if you don't dump a bunch of code. I've done it myself before. We were all new at one point :)

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 gpus = (((gc/400)+(gt/25)+(go/10)+(gm/1000)+(gb/30)+(gg*2)+(gmg/1000))*((gr/gn)/25)
```

is missing a parenthesis, it should be:

```
gpus = (((gc/400)+(gt/25)+(go/10)+(gm/1000)+(gb/30)+(gg*2)+(gmg/1000))*((gr/gn)/25))
```

Comment: thanks, should i delete this now?